# How to pass data from textfield to another textfiled?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    var  secondController = segue.destination as! EditBillsViewController

    secondController.textField = items
    secondController.notesTextBox = notes
    secondController.billNameTextBox = billsName
    secondController.dateToPayTextBox = DatePickerText
    secondController.DailyReminerTextBox = DaysNotification
```

Comment: Add more info about your problem!

Comment: i want to move a text in a textfiled from a view controller to another empty textfiled in another view controller

Answer (score 1):

First you get the Text from your textfield and then set it to the text of your second textfield.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    guard let text = self.firstTextField.text else {
    print("something Went wrong")
    return
    }

    var secondController = segue.destination as! EditBillsViewController
    secondController.textFieldValue = text
    secondController.notesTextBox = notes
    secondController.billNameTextBox = billsName
    secondController.dateToPayTextBox = DatePickerText
    secondController.DailyReminerTextBox = DaysNotification

}
```

Comment: Look closer!! "    secondController.textField.text = text
"

Comment: it said fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: thats because you cannot set UI values in the Segue because they haven't been initialised yet! What you can do is to have a variable that holds the value of second textfield and then in you viewDidload of your second VC you can set the value of textField to that value.